# Place Tkinter window on specific workspace on Solaris

Tags: python, tkinter, x11, solaris

On a Solaris system with the CDE desktop environment which has 6 'workspaces', which are like virtual desktops. There is a tool that shows the different name for the desktops and lets you move windows from one to the other, `stdwinlst`
The problem I am having is that windows that are spawned by Tkinter are spawned on the active workspace. Is there a way to force a window to spawn on a particular one?

Comment: If anywhere, any option to do so is probably buried somewhere in this document:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3899/index.html  It's been a long time since I've used CDE, but if there is a way to start an application and have it appear in a specific workspace, you might want to try doing that and seeing what command-line options or environment variables CDE sets for the child app process.

Comment: Another approach could be to save your CDE session with some apps running, then exit the session and restore it (I don't remember how to do that...).  Then go through the saved files and figure out how `dtsession` knows which workspace to put the apps back into.